# How to secure session cookies in jquery mobile web app

Tags: jquery, session, cookies

I am using the jquery.session.js plugin to set and use the session on client site using the following code:

```
$.session.set("mysessionvaribale", mysessionvalue)
```

And I have add  `httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true"`, this to my web.config file, I am using Https request through out the project but still the cookies not secure. I have also add the screen shot.

Comment: What do you mean they're not secure? Nothing can be hidden if it's on the client. If you want to prevent the user from tampering, use server-side sessions.

Comment: Yes i understand, in server site it is working fine but i have to use it in jquery mobile app.

Comment: What do you mean by they're not secure?

Comment: I mean when i see in the console under cookies section then the value of httpOnly and security is empty but this should be tick.

Comment: The options you set in `web.config` only apply to cookies sent from the server. If you create a cookie on the client, you have to set the options there. I'm not familiar with the plugin you're using, check its documentation to see how to do this.

Comment: OK thanks for your time. i will take another try at my end and read out plugin documentation.
Thanks